# QEventLoop for synchronous wait for signal

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm using Qt5, QCoreApplication.
In order to allow for readable and easy to maintain code, I need to write a blocking method in a class/thread A that will emit a signal, connected to a slot in a different thread B, and then wait for an answer or a timeout to occur asynchronously in thread B.
I have first been thinking about what felt like a natural solution: let thread B reply with a signal connected to a slot in thread A, and somehow wait for it. It seems QEventLoop can do that for me. But I keep reading contradictory statements: that's the pattern but avoid it if you can :-).
I'm pretty sure I could achieve my purpose by blocking A on a 0 QSemaphore that B would release when ready. The code would probably not be much more complex that way.
What do you experienced Qt developers think?
Is there a good solution or do you find some symptoms of flawed analysis in my description (i.e. do you think I should never ever need to do something like that? :-))?

Answer (score 3):

The key ingredient you can leverage is the `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`.

This connection type lets you pass return value from a slot. You can use it in a signal-slot connection. You can also directly invoke the slot without using a signal through the `QMetaMethod::invoke` / `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` mechanism.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class Master : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL bool mySignal();
  Q_SLOT void process() {
    if (mySignal()) { // this can be a blocking call
      qDebug() << "success!";
    }
    thread()->quit();
  }
};

class Slave : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SLOT bool mySlot() {
    // do whatever processing is needed here
    // It's OK to call QCoreApplication::processEvents here
    return true;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  QThread masterThread, slaveThread;
  Master master;
  Slave slave;
  master.moveToThread(&masterThread);
  slave.moveToThread(&slaveThread);
  slave.connect(&master, SIGNAL(mySignal()), SLOT(mySlot()),
                Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
  masterThread.start();
  slaveThread.start();
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&master, "process");
  masterThread.wait();
  slaveThread.quit();
  slaveThread.wait();
  return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about the Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection return value. I can't seem to find it in the official Qt documentation. Am I missing  it? It does however not solve my problem, since my thread B cannot produce the answer synchronously. After a night's sleep, I think I'm gonna go for a state machine in thread B (my main thread) instead. Threads are for people who can't program state machines, right? Still, I would have up voted your answer if only I had a little more reputation. Cheers.

Comment: @nilo The blocking queued connection is certainly documented. Just look for what arguments does `connect` take.

Comment: @nilo I don't understand what you mean that slave thread cannot produce the answer synchronously. One thread must be in control, and the other thread is subordinate. The call on the slave thread is completely synchronous - it happens only when the control locus is in that thread's event loop (so the thread is not busy doing anything else), and only with the master thread blocked and waiting for the result.

Comment: @nilo If you want thread A to be asynchronous to thread B, then simply don't use a blocking connection. Thread A sends a signal to thread B, then sometime later thread B sends a signal to thread A, and thread A decides at that time what to do next. That's exactly how state machines work, and there's no blocking involved at all. A properly designed state machine is completely asynchronous and only executes short operations. `QStateMachineFramework` is your friend.

Comment: @ober About BlockingQueuedConnection, documentation says: "Same as QueuedConnection, except the current thread blocks until the slot returns. This connection type should only be used where the emitter and receiver are in different threads.". Does not say anything about the return value. Again, there might be some other documentation explaining that, but nothing I have found.

Comment: @ober Sorry about your user name for some reason, (at)kuba disappears when I save my comment.

Comment: @ober 100% in agreement on state machine solution. I have started using and liking it. I am quite used to asynchronous programming and state machines in other environments.

Comment: @ober I was however considering an alternative in this case. To draw a parallel, assume that thread A has a synchronous HTTP get(). Inside get(), thread A would send a signal to thread B. When receiving it, thread B would just forward it and return to its event loop.

Comment: @ober  After a while, thread B would either receive and answer from the HTTP server, or time out (voluntarily oversimplified). It would then have to signal thread A, that during all that time has been hanging in some kind of blocking system call (QEventLoop::exec(), QSemaphore::acquire(), or whatever is most appropriate, which was the topic for my question).

Comment: @ober My alternative, currently under implementation is to simply not implement a synchronous method at all and to keep everything asynchronous. In that case, I don't even have a need for so called thread A (B is in fact my QCoreApplication).

Comment: @nilo The at-username requires removal of spaces. Alas, the thread A can certainly block - that's what the blocking connection is for. All you need to do in thread B is to run *its* event loop inside of the slot. That's fine, and removes this implementation detail from thread A.

Comment: @nilo [This](http://blog.think-async.com/2009/08/secret-sauce-revealed.html) should solve your conundrum. The code can be written completely in a synchronous style. I will show a Qt-friendly example of its use in a separate Q/A.

Comment: @ober I had no space, just (at)kuba. Anyway. The example at your link did seem relevant, although I don't clearly see how to transpose it to clean Qt. "run its event loop indide of the slot"? Not clear to me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @nilo Inside the slot you can certainly make an instance of QEventLoop and call its exec() method.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to emit a signal in your thread, which means your main thread will have a slot to connect you thread signal, it is simple, just emit it.
but if you want a slot in your thread, and receive signal and so something in your thread, you have to use QEventloop in you run method.

usually, I will just use QThread::wait to wait for other thread end.

be careful here, some Qt objects cannot work across the thread like QSql* and QTcpSocket....